# Multiple updates to the same object simultaneously from different clients using MongoDB

Tags: c#, mysql, mongodb

Before I make the switch for a customer away from the traditional MySQL database, I need a bit better understanding on how (if at all possible) one may have multiple clients connected to a MongoDB on the same entry, to handle a problem where multiple updates to the same record can be handled in the following circumstances :

- A: Each client makes a change to a different 'field' in the same object
- B: Each client makes a change to the same 'field' in the same object

In a MySQL situation, it is fairly simple (but possible) to handle both cases.

Case 'A' would be handled mostly in code, so that the `UPDATE` request only updates the field that was changed, which would result in a no comflict scenario where each clients change does not have an impact on any other clients change due to the `field` being different in the update request.

Case 'B' happens on a Last-in basis, where the client update requests are processed in the order received, and (in the unlikely scenario) if two are received simultaneously (exact same nanosecond), then the order to update is random.

What I understand about MongoDB (as an example of object storage), is that there are no records and fields per se, and that objects are retrieved as you have them structured. So given the following :

```
class Person {
    int id;
    string Name;
    string Address
}
```

If both clients retrieved the same `Person` object, and one client made a change to `Person.Name` only; and another client made a change to `Person.Address`, that the only way to update this object in the MongoDB, would be to send the whole `Person` object as originally retrieved with the modified field.

Wouldn't this cause a problem where the last client updating `Person.Address` would end up overwriting the `Person.Name` change sent by the first client ?  If so, is there any way to make this work with the power of a traditional database where each field can be updated independent of the other fields on the same record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the behavior of MongoDB in this case depends on which operation you choose. findAndModify is an atomic operation which locks, reads, modifies, writes, and unlocks the document, therefore blocking concurrent reads/writes.

This way, client A can modify Person.Address while client B attempts to modify Person.Name, and nothing will be overwritten, since client B's findAndModify will be blocked from reading until client A completes the operation.

Update: the corresponding atomic method in the .Net C# driver is UpdateOneAsync.

Comment: Could you give an example of `findAndModify` .  Typically, I would select the data set and just query for what I need using Linq.

Comment: Are you using the official MongoDB .NET driver in C#?

Comment: If so, it looks like the UpdateOneAsync method provides the atomicity that you require. https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update/

Comment: yes, I am using the official driver -- mongodb-csharp-driver or something to that effect

Comment: Visit this link for a couple simple examples using UpdateOneAsync: https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update/